# UserID null when trying to connect from .NET 6 to SQL Server through docker

Tags: c#, docker, .net-6.0

When trying to run my API through docker, I'm getting the following error message:

> 2024-03-18 11:50:22 Unhandled exception. System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'User ID')
> 2024-03-18 11:50:22    at Microsoft.Data.Common.ADP.CheckArgumentNull(Object value, String parameterName)
> 2024-03-18 11:50:22    at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionStringBuilder.SetValue(String keyword, String value)
> 2024-03-18 11:50:22    at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionStringBuilder.set_UserID(String value)
> 2024-03-18 11:50:22    at Program.$(String[] args) in Program.cs:line 22

This is my `appsettings.Development.json` where I'm defining the user id and password:

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "SQLDbConnection": "Server=localhost,1433;Initial Catalog=db;",
  },
  "UserId": "sa",
  "Password": "passw0rd"
}
```

Here is my `program.cs` where I'm trying to connect:

```
// Connect to server using connection string from appSettings.Development.json
var sqlConBuilder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();

sqlConBuilder.ConnectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("SQLDbConnection");;

// Use user ID and password directly from configuration
sqlConBuilder.UserID = builder.Configuration["UserId"];
sqlConBuilder.Password = builder.Configuration["Password"];

builder.Services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>(opt => opt.UseSqlServer(sqlConBuilder.ConnectionString));
```

Comment: Have you debugged your code seen what Environment is used and therefore what configuration was loaded? Deployed into/via docker i assume it not considered development.

Comment: When you publish your app, it will run in ``Production`` mode. so you need to put your setting in ``appsettings.json`` or ``appsetting.Production.json``.